# UV Editing screen not showing/available

Tags: interface

Up in the Screens menu my *UV Editing* has disappeared. How can I get it back?

Comment: you have deleted it ?!

Comment: I don't know. Is there a way to get it back if I did?

Comment: file->load factory settings,  but this will reset all the settings you have (not files )

Comment: read: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Arranging_frames

Answer (score 3):

The screens can be be deleted by clicking the <kbd>X</kbd> button or added by the <kbd>+</kbd> button on the info header , when you create new one you should save the start-up file to keep it for other sessions

[image]

To get the the default screens back you have to reset all the user settings to default from File->Load Factory Settings

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just as a reference I'll post the shortcuts for the different window types

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> = Logic Editor

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> = Node Editor

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> = Console

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> = 3D View

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd> = Graph Editor

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> = Properties

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> = Video Sequence Editor

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd> = Outliner

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> = UV/Image Editor

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd> = Text Editor

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> = Dope Sheet